# Limitation of SQL in BigQuery vs Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

While comparing Cloud Spanner vs BigQuery, Am trying to figure what kind of limitations there are in BigQuery's in SQL, compared to ANSI SQL (select part only) ?

Does BigQuery support all complex joins of ANSI SQL ?

Additionally, is there anything that Cloud Spanner can do and BigQuery cannot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) is compliant with the SQL 2011 standard and has extensions that support querying nested and repeated data.
You can see about [SELECT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-list) and [JOINS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types) and other details of the BigQuery Standard SQL in [Query Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) documentation

> Additionnally, is there anything than Spanner can do and BigQuery cannot ?

Main difference between BigQuery and Spanner:

```
BigQuery - Large scale data warehouse service with append-only tables  
Spanner  - A horizontally scalable, globally consistent, relational database service
```

`Foreign Keys`, `Transaction support`, `Indexes` - are good examples of what is supported in Spanner but not in BigQuery
Note: *above not supported features are by design and reflect respective purpose of those two products. What is "a must" feature for one is even conceptually not in another. Comparing BigQuery and Spanner is close to comparing Hadoop and mySQL for example if this will make it easier for you to imagine.*

I think it would be great if you read respective documentations and then ask specific questions

[cloud.google.com/­bigquery/­docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/)
[cloud.google.com/­spanner/­docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs)

Comment: Why the need of Spanner ?

Comment: in short - BigQuery is for analytical workloads, whereas Spanner is for transaction processing

Comment: You mean : BigQuery is bad for relationnal join and Spanner excels in it ?

Comment: Nope :o) I meant: BigQuery is totally bad for transaction processing whereas Spanner **suppose** to excel in it! For what BigQuery is - its JOIN ability is quite good I think!

Comment: You mean, BigQuery is bad for Insert/delete and Spanner excels in transactionnal insert/delete.

Comment: you can say this way :o)